# Как описать контроллер Java для страницы JSP c формой для ввода данных и таблицей

Tags: java, mvc, spring-mvc

**Доброго времени!**

Ребята подскажите пожалуйста как описать контроллер для страницы JSP c таблицей и формой для ввода данных?
В форму должны вводится параметры для фильтрации данных в этой таблице.

Т.е. есть таблица, в которую подгружаются данные из БД и есть форма для ввода данных, по которым должны осуществляться новые запросы к БД и их результат обновлять таблицу.

Как описать контроллер отдельно для таблицы и отдельно для формы запроса данных разобрался, но как в одном контроллере совместить и то и другое не знаю (

Пытался получить параметры из формы с помощью @RequestParam, и этим же контроллером перегрузить эту же страницу, но не получилось, потому что @RequestParam не берёт значение из формы

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/main", method = RequestMethod.GET)//Mapping web context, на который будет реагировать метод
public String main(Model uiModel, @RequestParam("latitude") String latitude, @RequestParam("longitude") String longitude) throws Exception {
    List<WeatherOpenMap> listWeatherOpenMap=weatherOpenMapService.getWeatherForecast(latitude,longitude);
    uiModel.addAttribute("listForecastOpenMap",listWeatherOpenMap);
    List<FloodView> listFloodViews=floodService.getAllFloodViev();
    uiModel.addAttribute("listFlood",listFloodViews);
    return "main_page";
}
```

Страница "main_page":

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Главная страница</title>  
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <table class="flood">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Координаты</th>
            <th>Населённый пункт</th>
            <th>Дата</th>
            <th>Время</th>
            <th>Дождь</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${listFlood}" var="flood">
            <tr>
                <td class="geo">${flood.geographKoordsPost}</td>
                <td>${flood.nameLocality}</td>
                <td>${flood.date}</td>
                <td>${flood.time}</td>
                <td>${flood.snow}</td>
           </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div>
<form method="post" action="/fast-water/water/main">
    <input type="text" path="latitude"/>
    <input type="text" path="longitude"/>
    <input type="text" path="yearStart"/>
    <input type="text" path="monthStart"/>
    <input type="text" path="dayStart"/>
    <input type="text" path="yearFinish"/>
    <input type="text" path="monthFinish"/>
    <input type="text" path="dayFinish"/>
    <button>Обновить данные</button>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Добавил у @RequestParam значение по умолчанию, что бы при начальной загрузки страницы не выдавало исключения об отсутствии параметра

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/main", method = RequestMethod.GET)//Mapping web context, на который будет реагировать метод
public String main(Model uiModel, @RequestParam(value = "latitude",defaultValue ="55.01") String latitude, @RequestParam(value = "longitude",defaultValue ="55.01") String longitude) throws Exception {
    List<WeatherOpenMap> listWeatherOpenMap=weatherOpenMapService.getWeatherForecast(latitude,longitude);
    uiModel.addAttribute("listForecastOpenMap",listWeatherOpenMap);
   // WeatherDarkSky WeatherDarkSky=weatherDarkSkyService.getWeatherForecast("2019-05-23T10:00:00","55.09","51.07");
    List<FloodView> listFloodViews=floodService.getAllFloodViev();
    uiModel.addAttribute("listFlood",listFloodViews);
    return "main_page";
}
```

Но передать новый параметр из формы не получается

Comment: Связывать вью с базой данных не очень хороший вариант

Comment: наверное, но это учебный проект, пока так пойдёт

Answer (score 0):

Для решения данной проблемы нужно:
1) Прописать у параметров значения по умолчанию, чтобы при первой загрузки не возникало исключение об их отсутствии, ну и чтобы было с чем работать внутри контроллера за одно:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/main", method = RequestMethod.GET)//Mapping web context, на который будет реагировать метод
public String main(Model uiModel, @RequestParam(value = "latitude",defaultValue ="55.01") String latitude, @RequestParam(value = "longitude",defaultValue ="55.01") String longitude) throws Exception {
    List<WeatherOpenMap> listWeatherOpenMap=weatherOpenMapService.getWeatherForecast(latitude,longitude);
    uiModel.addAttribute("listForecastOpenMap",listWeatherOpenMap);
   // WeatherDarkSky WeatherDarkSky=weatherDarkSkyService.getWeatherForecast("2019-05-23T10:00:00","55.09","51.07");
    List<FloodView> listFloodViews=floodService.getAllFloodViev();
    uiModel.addAttribute("listFlood",listFloodViews);
    return "main_page";
}
```

2) В форме на странице у Button прописать тип "submit" - это указывает на то, что данный запрос должен уйти на сервер:

```html
<form name="form2" method="GET" action="/fast-water/water/main">
        <input type="text" name="latitude2"/>
        <input type="text" name="longitude2"/>
        <input type="text" name="yearStart2"/>
        <input type="text" name="monthStart2"/>
        <input type="text" name="dayStart2"/>
        <input type="text" name="yearFinish2"/>
        <input type="text" name="monthFinish2"/>
        <input type="text" name="dayFinish2"/>
        <button tybe="submit">Загрузить</button>
    </form>
```